# Two master views(one from left and one from right) in Spit View

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to create navigation in my app using `Split View Controller`. I don't want to mess with the "philosophy" of Split View Controllers - One thin master view on left and one thick detail view on right. I would like to accomplish, though, when I click button in detail view, that the master view will slide left and hide and NEW thin view(master view-like, but with some minor data) will slide from right. I saw it in Google Drive App for iPad.

My questions:

**1)** Is it OK with Apple to do something like this?(Xcode sometimes warns me, that Split View needs to be root VC etc...)

**2)** Is it pain to implement it?

**3)** Are there any hints or workarounds when implementing it?